# Converto date in Java to integer and then to Delphi Time

Tags: java, delphi, parsing, date, time

I have a server-equipment configuration where I need to change the equip date config, using UDP. The server is written in Java and the equipment, in Delphi.

So, the flow of the data is this:

`Java server (Java date) -> UDP (integer date) -> Delphi equipment (Delphi date)`

The problem is that when I pass the date as an integer, java calculates miliseconds from 1970, and Delphi, seconds. I pass then the date as following: `today.getTime() / 1000`, but the equipment understands this as a 2008 date, when we're on 2012.

I can change the Java code, but the equipment is 3rd party and I don't have access to it's source code.

There's difference between Java and Delphi date parsing that allow this discrepancy?

**EDIT:**
Thanks to MДΓΓ БДLL I noticed I was multiplying by 1000 instead of dividing by it, I now have a better date, but still wrong (was somewhen in 2033, now it's in 2008).

Comment: I don't fully understand. You need to go from milliseconds since 1970 to seconds (since 1970?) but you're _multiplying_ by 1000? Milliseconds => seconds means _divide_ by 1000.

Comment: I don't know of any Date types in Delphi that are seconds since 1970. Are you sure this is a Delphi question?

Comment: Doh! I was indeed multiplying instead of dividing... but it still didn't fix the problem, see the edit

Comment: @Marcus - it is int64; see `UnixToDateTime` function from DateUtils.pas

Comment: The time "in Delphi" is the same as the rest of Greece. ;) http://maps.google.co.uk/maps/place?q=Delphi,+greece

Comment: @Serg: Thanks. I never noticed recent versions of Delphi had that; I posted my own functions, which work on all Delphi versions back to Delphi 1 instead. Thanks for that pointer. :)

Comment: @Rodrigo, if you're still having issues, please provide inputs and outputs again. `$4F032500` into `UnixToDateTime` yields `1/3/2012 3:55:44 PM`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Unix time stamp is the same as the one used in Java. Delphi's TDateTime, on the other hand, is based on a starting date of 12:01 AM on 12/30/1899 (it's a COM compatibility thing), so some conversion is necessary. These functions  will do it; I've also added a quick piece of test code to show the conversion works correctly both ways.

```
const
  UnixStartDate = 25569.0;

function DateTimeToUnixTime(const ADateTime: TDateTime): Cardinal;
begin
  Result := Round(ADateTime - UnixStartDate) * 86400;
end;

function UnixTimeToDateTime(const UnixDate: Cardinal): TDateTime;
begin
  Result := UnixDate / 86400 + UnixStartDate;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var  StartDate: TDateTime;
  UnixDate: Cardinal;
begin
  StartDate := Date();
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Start Date: ' + DateToStr(StartDate));
  UnixDate := DateTimeToUnixTime(StartDate);
  Memo1.Lines.Add('DateTimeToUnixTime = ' + IntToStr(UnixDate));
  Memo1.Lines.Add('UnixTimeToDateTime = ' + DateToStr(UnixTimeToDateTime(UnixDate)));
end;
```

Comment: For all the non-colonials (? I think the british are responsible for that format?) who have no idea what `12:01 AM` is.. it's `0:01` NOT `12:01` ;)

Comment: It's `0001` or `0:01` for those people using 24 hour time; in 12-hour (AM/PM) format it's `12:01AM` as I said. :)

Comment: Yeah I just wanted to make it sound a bit more fun ;) But as someone who grew up with the 24hour system myself I thought it warranted some mention as you wouldn't believe how many people (at least in Germany/Austria) would intuitively interpret `12:01AM` as `12:01` - or would be stumped why exactly any value larger than `12:00` is allowed in a 12hour time system to begin with.

Comment: @KenWhite: -1. Unix timestamps are expressed in **seconds** from the Unix epoch, but Java timestamps are expressed in **milliseconds** from the same epoch. Your `DateTimeToUnixTime()` function encodes `Jan 3 2012 3:55:44 PM GMT` as `1325635200`, but the correct value in Unix is `1325606144` and in Java is `1325606144000`. `UnixTimeToDateTime(1325635200)` is then returning `Jan 4 2012 00:00:00 GMT`. I just updated my answer with examples that produce correct values.

Comment: On Delphi XE, DateTimeToUnix() and UnixToDateTime(), you can use natively from System.DateUtils. And these functions return corrret the value 1325606144 for Jan 4 2012 15:55:44, sou you can use: YourJavaValue := DateTimeToUnix(YourDateTimeValue) * 1000;

Answer (score 6):

Delphi's `DateUtils` unit has `UnixToDateTime()` and `DateTimeToUnix()` functions for converting between `TDateTime` and Unix timestamps, which are expressed as **seconds from the Unix epoch**  (Jan 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT):

```
// 1325606144 = Jan 3 2012 3:55:44 PM GMT

uses
  DateUtils;

var
  DT: TDateTime;
  Unix: Int64;
begin
  DT := UnixToDateTime(1325606144);
  // returns Jan 3 2012 3:55:44 PM

  Unix := DateTimeToUnix(EncodeDate(2012, 1, 3) + EncodeTime(15, 55, 44, 0));
  // returns 1325606144
end;
```

Java's `Date` class, on the other hand, is based on **milliseconds from the Unix epoch** instead.  That is easy to take into account, though:

```
uses
  DateUtils;

function JavaToDateTime(Value: Int64): TDateTime;
begin
  Result := UnixToDateTime(Value div 1000);
end;

function DateTimeToJava(const Value: TDateTime): Int64;
begin
  Result := DateTimeToUnix(Value) * 1000;
end;
```

Alternatively:

```
uses
  SysUtils, DateUtils;

// UnixDateDelta is defined in SysUtils...

function JavaToDateTime(Value: Int64): TDateTime;
begin
  Result := IncMilliSecond(UnixDateDelta, Value);
 end;

function DateTimeToJava(const Value: TDateTime): Int64;
begin
  Result := MilliSecondsBetween(UnixDateDelta, Value);
  if Value < UnixDateDelta then
    Result := -Result;
end;
```

Either way:

```
// 1325606144000 = Jan 3 2012 3:55:44 PM GMT

var
  DT: TDateTime;
  Java: Int64;
begin
  DT := JavaToDateTime(1325606144000);
  // returns Jan 3 2012 3:55:44 PM

  Java := DateTimeToJava(EncodeDate(2012, 1, 3) + EncodeTime(15, 55, 44, 0));
  // returns 1325606144000
end;
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. The function returned TDateTime values from the year 43,000.

Comment: Feel free to enlighten me as to the correct usage rather than to state I was using it incorrectly. I had success using the JavaToDelphiDateTime function from the SuperObject package which is used by Delphi-OOP.

Comment: I have updated my answer with examples. I did not take seconds vs milliseconds into account before.

Comment: Very usefull. Thanks. Note that UnixToDateTime and DateTimeToUnix both have an optional ReturnUTC parameter that is true by default.

Comment: The `ReturnUTC` parameter does not exist in XE2, so it must have been added more recently.

Answer (score 3):

As far I know Java date is based on UTC so you also have to convert local time from/to UTC.
These functions use milliseconds, adapt the code to your needs.

```
function TzSpecificLocalTimeToSystemTime(
  lpTimeZoneInformation: PTimeZoneInformation;
  lpLocalTime, lpUniversalTime: PSystemTime): BOOL; stdcall; external 'kernel32.dll';

function SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime(
  lpTimeZoneInformation: PTimeZoneInformation;
  lpUniversalTime, lpLocalTime: PSystemTime): BOOL; stdcall; external 'kernel32.dll';

function JavaToDelphiDateTime(const dt: int64): TDateTime;
var
  t: TSystemTime;
begin
  DateTimeToSystemTime(25569 + (dt / 86400000), t);
  SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime(nil, @t, @t);
  Result := SystemTimeToDateTime(t);
end;

function DelphiToJavaDateTime(const dt: TDateTime): int64;
var
  t: TSystemTime;
begin
  DateTimeToSystemTime(dt, t);
  TzSpecificLocalTimeToSystemTime(nil, @t, @t);
  Result := Round((SystemTimeToDateTime(t) - 25569) * 86400000)
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Get the JSON superobect package from www.progdigy.com and extract the functions JavaToDelphiDateTime and v.v. from the source files.</strike>

Updated 3 Mar 2014:

Progdigy.com no longer serves these files. Get the files from Google. The official 1.2.4 ZIP file in the download section http://code.google.com/p/superobject/downloads/list dates from 2010, but the individual files in http://code.google.com/p/superobject/source/browse have updates up until Oct 2012.

You **must** use those updated files because there was an obscure error in datetime conversions happening around the switch to daylight savings time in leapyears.